# Images, fonts, favicons etc appear only in Safari but don't in Chrome or mobile?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

So I'm making a website and using Safari as the browser of choice. I decide to open the website in chrome but the font and images are broken. I tried the same thing on my phone, but there ONLY the image is broken.

Here's the website:
dikril.viliworld.eu/Archive

heres the image that has to show up in the top left corner but doesn't.:
https://dikril.viliworld.eu/Archive/images/Dikril-white-print.svg

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. 
Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Answer (score 0):

Please delete your invalid manifest line in your html-file. Chrome is using it, safari not.